# Question related to topology

Tags: general-topology

Prove that a topological product of uncountably many metric spaces, each
having more than one element, is never metrizable.

Comment: Why downvote? Is statement incorrect?

Comment: no it is correct, I need it to be proven

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am sorry about  not telling you where I got stuck.  I said since I is not countable there will be infinietly many elements j which U_j not equal to X_j

Comment: I am sorry about  not telling you where I got stuck. I said since I is not countable there will be infinietly many NBHD basis . And since the product of infinitely metric space has to have a countable NBRH basis that will contradict I so that will make the product of infinitely metric space not metrizable but I am not convinced

Answer (score 2):

A basic open set is 
$$\prod U_i$$ where $U_i\subseteq X_i$ is open and for all but finitely many $i$, $U_i=X_i$.

Now let $O_n$ be a countable number of basic open sets and assume that 
$$\bigcap O_n\neq \emptyset$$

Then there is an index $i$ such that for all $n$ the $i$th coordinate of $O_n$ is $X_i$. Since $X_i$ has more than one element we see that 
$\bigcap O_n$ also must have more than one element. This implies that the space is non metrizable for in a metric space 
$$\{x\}=\bigcap B_x(\frac{1}{n})$$

Comment: Thank you but I still have a question .Does the NBHD here countable or not? if it is not how to prove it